# Open SSL throwing unknown option '-n' in Amazon Linux2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, saltstack, amazon-linux-2

My code throws error when it reaches this line:

`{% set encrypted_password = salt['cmd.run']('openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -md md5 -in <(echo -n  "' + ssm_plaintext_password +'") -pass pass:'+random_password) %}`

Error:

```
[ERROR   ] Command '[u'openssl', u'enc', u'-aes-128-cbc', u'-a', u'-salt', u'-md', u'md5', u'-in', u'<(echo', u'-n', u'g0vknM6a%,)', u'-pass', u'pass:zHwhIwKesJVXZO9taCHuEVGSPTW3J95g']' failed with return code: 1
[ERROR   ] stdout: unknown option '-n'
```

But when I run the command **openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -md md5 -in <(echo -n  "g0vknM6a%,") -pass pass:zHwhIwKesJVXZO9taCHuEVGSPTW3J95g** it gives me the input.

I am executing this in **Amazon Linux2** based instance having **Python3** and **salt-call 2019.2.0 (Fluorine)** . Is this due to any binary version changes as this code worked perfectly with **Amazon Linux1**

Answer (score 0):

Add the `python_shell=True` option to `cmd.run`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/448076)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here : https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/44226.

I replaced cmd.run with cmd.shell and this works fine for me.